# What does Sensitivity of Personal mean on an Appointment in Outlook?

Tags: outlook

I have a VBA macro to schedule Outlook appointments from Excel. One of the properties of an AppointmentItem is [Sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.sensitivity). When it is set to [olPrivate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olsensitivity), the Private padlock icon turns on, and olNormal turns this off.

[image: Private icon]

What do olPersonal and olConfidential do?

Comment: Already reviewed this?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mark-your-email-as-normal-personal-private-or-confidential-4a76d05b-6c29-4a0d-9096-71784a6b12c1

Comment: Why not set the Sensitivity property to one of these values and see what happens in Outlook?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I did, but saw no effect.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks. I saw that page but it only called out emails, not appointments. Reading a little more carefully, I see that those values for emails puts "Please treat this as Personal" in the InfoBar for the recipient. I will send an appointment to someone and ask if they see it.

Comment: @TheRizza - here is your answer then :-)